# in jsFiddle, <ol> don't display leading number, why?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, jsfiddle

My css code:

```
ol {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

My HTML code:

```
<ol>
    <li>This is the first.</li>
    <li>This is the second.</li>
</ol>
```

[my Code is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/unimous/XMrbu/2/)

Why they don't display the leading number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the fiddle site itself causing it. If you use a DOM inspector on the list nodes, you'll see that a Fiddle css stylesheet (normalize.css) is overriding your own stylesheet.

If you uncheck the "Normalized CSS" box on the left-hand side of the Fiddle window, the list elements will be numbered as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It's displaying per se, it's just not visible because of the way jsfiddle's CSS resets margins to 0.  Try this:

```
ol {
    list-style-type: decimal;
    margin: 0 2em;
}
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/XMrbu/7/

Comment: Yup - it's getting hidden by the margin because list-style-position is set to outside.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you **don't** need to use

```
ol {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

Since it is the default. `Normalized CSS` is causing the problem.